# Spring Security deployment error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, glassfish-4

For the last 4 hours I've been trying to solve the issue, but I simply can't see what is  wrong with it.. [And it's not even a midnight yet :) ]

I'm having a trouble to deploy a Spring MVC application on Glassfish server.

Here's the output of Glassfish.

```
cannot Deploy kShop 
deploy is failing=Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0];
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0' while setting constructor argument with key [2];
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager';
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0' while setting constructor argument;
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation;
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting constructor argument with key [0];
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager#0' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService';
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource';
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataSource' is defined.
Please see server.log for more details.
```

Here's the **web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/kshop-security.xml</param-value>

    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Spring Security -->  
    <filter>  
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
        <filter-class>  
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy  
        </filter-class>  
     </filter>  

    <filter-mapping>  
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>   
    </filter-mapping>  

</web-app>
```

The **kshop-security.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <security:http auto-config="true"  use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <security:form-login login-page="/login"
            default-target-url="/" authentication-failure-url="/fail2login" />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <!-- <security:user-service> <security:user name="admin" password="password" 
                authorities="ROLE_USER" /> </security:user-service> -->
            <security:jdbc-user-service
                data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="select username, password, active from users where username=?"
                authorities-by-username-query="select us.username, ur.authority from users us, user_roles ur 
        where us.user_id = ur.user_id and us.username =?  " />
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

And **servlet-context.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="org.shahapps.kshop" />
    <context:property-placeholder location="/resources/database.properties" /> 


    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </beans:bean>


</beans:beans>
```

Please help me out here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This stack trace element gives away the problem

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataSource' is defined.
```

The root context loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` does not have access to the beans declared in the servlet context loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`. Therefore, the bean named `dataSource` in `servlet-context.xml` is not accessible to the `authentication-manager` in `kshop-security.xml`.

You will have to reorganize your context so that the beans needed in `kshop-security.xml` are available to it. This can simply mean moving the `dataSource` `<bean>` definition to another `root-context.xml` file (which you would register to also be loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`) or to the `kshop-security.xml` file directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your dataSource bean to this.

beans:bean id="dataSource" name="dataSource"

You've given it an id "dataSource" but no name "dataSource".

See the last line of your error.

Answer (score 0):

Add your servlet-context.xml to your contextConfigLocations in your web.xml:

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring/kshop-security.xml
    </param-value>
 </context-param>
```